# aiohttp with custom connector hangs on a request

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

I have a class called `Channel` with methods to handle my own stream with data, mainly:
`read(), write(), open(), end(), close(), incoming/outcoming_queue`. They do work and control any requests correctly.
I tried using it as a custom connector so that the user can do:

```py
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=self.custom_connector) as session:
            async with session.get(url) as resp:
                return await resp.text())
```

and it would let my custom_connector handle the request's target.

```py
class CustomConnector(aiohttp.BaseConnector):
    async def _create_connection(self, req, traces, timeout):
        # duplex_channel is an instance of the Channel class (described above).
        return duplex_channel
```

But currently, the code hangs on the `session.get(url)` line. I believe its because my Channel class is not what aiohttp would expect. Documentation mentions `ResponseHandler` but its not really dug deeper anywhere. **What methods should the object returned from the '_create_connection()' method implement**? What may I be missing here?

Comment: please provide Chanell class as well, it is impossible to say something without seeing MAIN part of ur code

Comment: @ElvinJafarov My question is rather general. If I know what should be implemented (or what type the returned object should be, or whatever) that would fix the problem, I hope.